# Cohort analysis in google data studio (month of reg vs month of purchase)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I have an ad hoc cohort analysis in google sheets and want to recreate in google data studio.

I have basically three tables: orders, users and marketing spend.
Orders and users live in google cloud PostgreSQL.
Marketing spend is per-month and lives in a spreadsheet.

**Orders** have:

- Money earned
- Payment date
- User ID
- A bunch of other data
  Full list:
  [full list of data field in orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qkbb.png)
  --

**Users** have:

- User ID
- User reg date
- Some other stuff
  Full list:
  [full list of data field in users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln1L8.png)

**Marketing spend** has:

- Date (first date for each month)
- Spend for a month
  Looks like that [marketing spend google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOCfv.png)

The google sheet I'm trying to recreate looks like that:
[cohort analysis to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bupep.jpg)

I imported all the data into the data studio but have no idea so far on how to achieve that.

What am I missing here?

Will provide all the details. Please help me figure this one out

Comment: Blending Orders and users by `user_id` gives the money per user. However, as far as I understand, the date difference in months between payment and user registration date is need. This cannot be done in Data Studio, because blending data does not allow formulas on top of it. Could you  do this join in Postgres as View/additonal table? Having one table, getting the date differences in months and reducing the registration date to month as possible in Data Studio. Blending with "Marketing spend" with the date is the last step.

Answer (score 0):

In Data Studio you can use the "pivot table with heat map" to obtain a similar result as in your Google Sheets examples.
Before that you will need to prepare your data source using PostgreSQL or BigQuery.

Next is an example in BigQuery:

```sql
WITH orders AS (
SELECT 
    '01' AS user_id,
    DATETIME(TIMESTAMP '2021-12-30T13:00:21Z') as order_payment_datetime,
    100.0 AS order_money_paid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '01' AS user_id,
    DATETIME(TIMESTAMP '2021-11-30T13:00:21Z') as order_payment_datetime,
    100.0 AS order_money_paid   
), users AS (
    SELECT '01' as user_id,
    DATETIME(TIMESTAMP '2021-11-30T13:00:21Z') as reg_date
), marketing AS (
    SELECT DATE '2021-11-01' AS mk_date,
    200.00 AS mk_spent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2021-12-01' AS mk_date,
    400.00 AS mk_spent
), cohort AS (
SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC(reg_date,MONTH) AS reg_date, 
    DATE_TRUNC(order_payment_datetime, MONTH) AS payment_date,
    DATETIME_DIFF(order_payment_datetime, reg_date, MONTH) as month_order,
    SUM(Order_money_paid) AS amount
FROM orders o INNER JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.user_id 
GROUP BY 1,2,3
) 
SELECT reg_date, month_order, amount, SAFE_DIVIDE(amount,m.mk_spent) as amount_per
FROM cohort c INNER JOIN marketing m ON c.Payment_date = m.mk_date 
ORDER BY reg_date, month_order
```

Use this as a source of your Data Studio report and then add a "Pivot table with a heat map".

I also wrote a blog post about how you can do cohort analysis in Data Studio [hodo.dev/posts/post-32-gcp-bigquery-cohort-report/](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-32-gcp-bigquery-cohort-report/).